# Linq Result Join all Rows Data to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, linq

I am getting data like `200k` records from the `database` and store it in a `linq` result with a `ColumnName` `EMAIL`. Now,I want to show all emails from the `linq` `result` and adding them to a `TextBox` by separating with a `,`.

Actually,I have prepared `DataTable` with that `linq` result and have combined all row data with the code :

```
var dataLists = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_LIST
                  where xx.EMAIL_GROUP_ID == ListGroupID
                  select xx).ToList();

DataTable DtDataLists = LINQToDataTable(dataLists);

EmailIDS = string.Join(",", DtDataLists.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["EMAILID"].ToString()).ToArray());
```

But,for preparing `DataTable`,it is taking a long time. 
So,I thought of preparing the `string` `EmailIDS` directly from the `linq` result.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can use `string.Join("," , dataLists.Select(x=> x.EmailId).ToArray())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should work for you but I'm not sure that it'll be much faster:

```
string.Join(",", dataLists.Select(x => x.EMAILID));
```

Comment: how about not allowing null values like :
I am getting null reference exception while having null values in my linq result .So, I want some thing like this :

var text=string.Join(",", table.AsEnumerable().Select(T => 
((T.ColumnName== null) ? "" : T.ColumnName).ToString()));

Comment: @RealSteel just add the filter statement (`Where`) to your expression.
`string.Join(",", dataLists.Where(x => x.EMAIL != null).Select(x => x.EMAILID));`

Comment: About the performance I did a little test, string.JOIN in combination with LINQ is high performant: http://www.dailycode.info/Blog/post/2014/05/07/Using-LINQ-to-concatinate-an-object-property-from-a-list-of-objects.aspx I do not see why you would use a datatable?